# How can we improve this code for better performance

Tags: php

This question was asked to me in an interview.
But I couldn't think of a way to improve it. can you improve this?

```
$target = array(1,rand(1,5));
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
   $target = array_merge( $target, array(rand($i,5),rand(1,$i)) ); 
}
```

Comment: well... I guess it was about array pre-allocation, to make it faster... so to use  array_pad() and array_map()

Comment: @FlashThunder it's really about `array_merge` overhead that gets proressively worse when you're merging into arrays with thousands of members. (See my comment to KenLee's answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array_merge has performance overhead,

So simply use

```
<?php

$target = array(1,rand(1,5));

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 

$target[]=rand($i,5);
$target[]=rand(1,$i);

}
```

You may add `var_dump($target);` to the end of the script (and to your original script) to see the result.

Original Code:
https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/96b0c

My answer:
https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/fc2a8

Comment: It'll store the multiple array inside $target array. while the actual code has only one array.
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2
)

Comment: It won't (did you try ??) . If in doubt, please check the two sandbox links in my answer

Comment: Very significant overhead at that. **2K** loops with `array_merge`: 0.0183 sec vs. `[]`: 0.0085 sec. **20K** loops: 2.3388 sec vs. 0.0251 sec. The `array_merge` approach degrades progressively with more members. **15K** loops: 0.5843 sec. **20K** loops: 2.3388 sec. **25K** loops: 4.7883 sec. **30K** loops: 8.2134 sec. **35K** loops: 12.4254 sec. **40K** loops: 17.444 sec. Didn't expect it to perform _that_ poorly! For contrast, **100K** loops with `[]`: 0.0217 sec. **1M** loops: 0.1438 sec. **5M** loops: 0.7272 sec. **10M** loops: 1.5533 sec (and 1GB memory for 20000002 integers in an array!).